# error "out of memory", "no such table: ZPHONE" and "malformed database schema (sqlite_master) - table sqlite_master already exists"

Tags: xcode, core-data, logging, out-of-memory

```
2011-11-11 15:48:01.885 BadgerNew[6926:11903] CoreData: error: (1) I/O error for database at /Users/Teguh/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/9390E83E-CC4B-49F7-B0CC-E2F591E7B8FC/Documents/BadgerNew.sqlite.  SQLite error code:1, 'out of memory'
2011-11-11 15:48:01.886 BadgerNew[6926:11903] CoreData: error: (1) I/O error for database at /Users/Teguh/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/9390E83E-CC4B-49F7-B0CC-E2F591E7B8FC/Documents/BadgerNew.sqlite.  SQLite error code:1, 'no such table: ZPHONE'
2011-11-11 15:48:01.887 BadgerNew[6926:15007] CoreData: error: (11) Fatal error.  The database at /Users/Teguh/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/9390E83E-CC4B-49F7-B0CC-E2F591E7B8FC/Documents/BadgerNew.sqlite is corrupted.  SQLite error code:11, 'out of memory'
2011-11-11 15:48:01.988 BadgerNew[6926:15007] CoreData: error: (11) Fatal error.  The database at /Users/Teguh/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/9390E83E-CC4B-49F7-B0CC-E2F591E7B8FC/Documents/BadgerNew.sqlite is corrupted.  SQLite error code:11, 'malformed database schema (sqlite_master) - table sqlite_master already exists'
2011-11-11 15:48:01.990 BadgerNew[6926:11903] CoreData: error: (11) Fatal error.  The database at /Users/Teguh/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/9390E83E-CC4B-49F7-B0CC-E2F591E7B8FC/Documents/BadgerNew.sqlite is corrupted.  SQLite error code:11, 'out of memory'
2011-11-11 15:48:01.998 BadgerNew[6926:11903] CoreData: error: (1) I/O error for database at /Users/Teguh/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/9390E83E-CC4B-49F7-B0CC-E2F591E7B8FC/Documents/BadgerNew.sqlite.  SQLite error code:1, 'no such table: ZPHONE'
```

what error is it? this log from Xcode versi4.2